# Removing breakpoints in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, breakpoints

I use Eclipse as IDE and I have a problem with breakpoints in this one. I have two projects - an android that I use as client app application and another one that I use as library for first one. Previously i have created an breakpoint in code of library application. Then this breakpoint was removed from sources. But now when I debug my code this breakpoint still hits (the file with *.class extension is opening and this breakpoint is showing). How can I disable or delete it?

Comment: Just double click on the break point will disable it or right click on the break point you can see the disable break option

Comment: it works if breakpoint is in java-file. But i have removed it from java-file. It hits in class-file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the project > select the debugging view >> Somewhere in that view there will be a window titled Breakpoints. From there you can remove the breakpoint you want to get rid of.

Comment: Great! Then you should mark this answer as the CORRECT answer. Don't simply upvote.

Comment: When i try to mark your answer i get the following message: "You can accept an answer in 8 minutes"

Comment: ok.. right your reputation is too low. Please come back and do that later. thx

Comment: @Junior222 you should be able to mark it correct now.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse try the following:

- Goto windows -> open perspective -> other -> debug
- click on Breakpoints tab in the
- Remove all/specific breakpoint by clicking on either cross/double cross button